# Tokenize sentence based on existing punctuation (TF-IDF vectorizer)

Tags: python, tokenize, tfidfvectorizer

In a dataframe, I have rows which include sentences like "*machine learning, data, ia, segmentation, analysis*" or "*big data, data lake, data visualisation, marketing, seo*".

I want to use TF-IDF and kmeans in order to create clusters based on each word.

My problem is that when I use TF-IDFvectorizer, it tokenizes sentences wrongly. I get terms like "*analyse analyse*" or "*english excel*" which are not supposed to be put together.

Instead, I would like sentences to be tokenized based on the commas in the sentence. So terms would be "*analyse*", "*big data*", "*data lake*", "*english*", etc.

I guess I should change something in the TF-IDFvectorize params but I don't understand how.

Do you please have any idea how to realize this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using keraslibray for Tokenization the sentence in dataframe .Before Tokenization remove the punctation in dataset of dataframe .TF-IDFvectorizer

I am attack the link check it

[Keras](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Check the example code that is help to tokenization of sentence

Comment: Another library NLTK are using for tokenization of sentence . I am share with you the link              https://www.guru99.com/tokenize-words-sentences-nltk.html

Comment: Thank you for the insight ! It works well !
Now I'm just trying to find out how to sort feature names :)

Comment: You can help this function